# Powershell differences between hash and other variables in global and local scopes

Tags: powershell

I noticed some differences in how Powershell manages global variables when they are changed in a local scope. In particular Associative Arrays (hash) seemes natively global, meanwhile the other variables types aren'nt globals and needs the prefix $global: (not just to read a value but to change it).

Here is my example:

```
# global variables test in powershell

$hash = @{}; # associative array
$hash["a"] = "Antenna";
$array = @(); # array
$array += "first";
$count = 1; # numeric
$glob = 1; # numeric

# here we change the values locally
function AddValues() {

    $hash["b"] = "Battle";

    Write-Host "local array"
    $array += "second";
    $array # write only "second" so is a local variable

    $local = 1;
    $local += 1;
    Write-Host "local sum result: $local" # here the sum result is 2 ok

    Write-Host "count locally: $count" # here the value is 1 ok
    $count += 1;
    Write-Host "count locally: $count" # here the value is still 1!!!
    $count = $count+1;
    Write-Host "count locally: $count" # here is 2 !!!

    $global:glob += 1;

}

# call the function
AddValues

Write-Host "hash" # here the hash is ok, has 2 values 
$hash 
Write-Host "array" # here the array has only "first" !!!
$array
Write-Host "count: $count" # here the value is just 1!!!
Write-Host "global: $($global:glob)" # here the value is ok (2)
```

How this is explained?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd create a more representative example with more varied values (initial as well as in operations) for numeric variables (e.g. `$count = 1000; # numeric initial` and `$count += 10;` and `$count = $count+100`…

Comment: Changing the value in a collection is not the same as changing the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Scoping rules only apply to *variables*!

PowerShell's default behavior is:

- You can transparently *read* variables in parent scopes
- Once you *write* to a variable, PowerShell creates a new local copy

But when you write to a specific key in a hashtable:

```
$hash["b"] = "value"
```

... you're not actually writing anything to the **variable** named "hash" - the variable still holds a reference to the exact same hashtable (which now happens to have more entries)!

If, on the other hand, we'd actually assigned a new value to the `$hash` *variable*, you'd see the behavior you're expecting:

```
function Update-Hash {
    $hash = @{"b" = "value"}
    $hash
}

$hash = @{"a" = 123}
$hash   # shows the a=123 entry
Update-Hash
$hash   # still shows a=123 entry, variable is untouched
```

The same goes for arrays, as well as property expressions.

---

If you want to ensure that the variable reference you've obtained is indeed local (and that you're not about to modify an object from the parent scope), use the `local` scope modifier:

```
function f
{
  if($false){
    # Oops
    $hash = @{}
  }

  # This will affect any $hash variable in the callers scope
  $hash['key'] = 'value'

  # This will, appropriately, throw an index exception
  $local:hash['key'] = 'value'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an illustration for [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889637/3439404) by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

```
$hash = @{}; # associative array
$hash["a"] = "Antenna";
$array  = @(); # array
$array += "first";
$count  = 1000; # numeric
$glob   = 2000; # numeric

# here we change the values locally
function AddValues() {
    $hash["b"] = "Battle";
    $array += "second";
    $local = 1;
    $local += 1;
    $count += 10;
    $count = $count+100;

    $global:glob += 2;
    '---Variables inside function'
    foreach ($varia in 'array','count','hash','glob','local') {
      foreach ($scope in 'Local','Global','Script',0,1) {
        Try {
            Get-Variable $varia -scope $scope  -ErrorAction Stop |
                Select-Object Name, Value, @{Name='Scope';Expression={$scope}}
        } catch {}
    } }
}
# call the function
AddValues

# How this is explained?
'Variables outside function'
foreach ($varia in 'array','count','hash','glob','local') {
  foreach ($scope in 'Local','Global','Script',0,1) {
    Try {
        Get-Variable $varia -scope $scope  -ErrorAction Stop |
            Select-Object Name, Value, @{Name='Scope';Expression={$scope}}
    } catch {}
} }
```

**Output** shows that *$array* local variable is created as a string inside the function (this behaviour has something to do with the `+=` operator and deserves more elaboration):

`.\SO\61888603.ps1`

> ```
> ---Variables inside function
>
> Name  Value   Scope 
> ----  -----   ----- 
> array second  Local 
> array {first} Global
> array {first} Script
> array second  0     
> array {first} 1     
> count 110     Local 
> count 1000    Global
> count 1000    Script
> count 110     0     
> count 1000    1     
> hash  {a, b}  Global
> hash  {a, b}  Script
> hash  {a, b}  1     
> glob  2002    Global
> glob  2002    Script
> glob  2002    1     
> local 2       Local 
> local 2       0     
> Variables outside function
> array {first} Local 
> array {first} Global
> array {first} Script
> array {first} 0     
> count 1000    Local 
> count 1000    Global
> count 1000    Script
> count 1000    0     
> hash  {a, b}  Local 
> hash  {a, b}  Global
> hash  {a, b}  Script
> hash  {a, b}  0     
> glob  2002    Local 
> glob  2002    Global
> glob  2002    Script
> glob  2002    0
> ```

Comment: Very nice explanatory device :D